# Method arguments in _.chain()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

When using the [`uniq()`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) method in underscore.js, we have the option of either a functional approach, or an OO aproach. Normally, uniq() takes an array, an `isSorted` boolean, and an `iterator` function. The boolean is for signalling whether or not the array has already been sorted. You can sort the array, then pass in `true` for better performance (apparently).

It might look something like this:

```
var data = [
    {'make':'Porsche','model':'911'},
    {'make':'Porsche','model':'986'},
    {'make':'Porsche','model':'986'}
];

var results = _.uniq(data, true, function (obj) {return obj.model});
```

For the chained version to work however, I’d have to do something like this:

```
var results = _.chain(data)
    .uniq(function (obj) {return obj.model})
    .value();
```

So, in the chained version, where does the `isSorted` argument go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chained version will apply the same function only complemented by the wrapped value, so it takes the same arguments. The equivalent to

```
_.uniq(data, true, function (obj) {return obj.model});
```

is

```
_(data).uniq(true, function (obj) {return obj.model});
```

and your invocation without `true` (the `isSorted` argument is optional, you can put the `iterator` mapper as second parameter as well) would be equivalent to

```
_.uniq(data, function (obj) {return obj.model});
```